# Change numbering style from 1. to (1)

Tags: lyx, enumerate, layout

I'm trying to change the numbering style in the Enumerate layout from displaying as:

1. xyz

to

(1) xyz

I've tried a few things by adding to the preamble, but mostly seem to be getting error messages. My feeling is that this is probably a simple fix, but I'd be grateful to know what to do here.

SW

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! Load package `enumitem` and use `\begin{enumerate}[label=(\arabic*)]` if it is for some lists, or `\setlist[enumerate, 1]{label=(\arabic*)}` (in the preamble) if it should be global.

Comment: This is perfect and very much appreciated. thank you!